# How do you sort elements as you add them to List (C++)?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to sort words as I add them to a list in C++. I must use lists, and I cannot use the "sort()" function.

I have a text file with some words (Each word is on a new line).

So far I have figured out how to collect the words and add them to a list:

```
fstream myfile(fileName);

if(!myfile) { // Test if file open
    cout<<"Error opening file"<< endl;
    return false;

}

while (getline(myfile, line)){ //loops through and gets sayings
    l.push_back(line);
}
```

The words are just added in the order that they are in the file. What I want to do is check the first letter of a word, and then put it in the appropriate position in the list, instead of just adding them to the end of the list.

Thank you in advance!

more info:

I believe I am supposed to use an iterator to accomplish this.

I know how to use an iterator to display the list:

```
for (list<string>::iterator it=l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it)
cout << *it << endl;
```

How would I use that to compare values before I add them? I tried to use the iterator to get the first letter of the word by using `(*it)[0]` but that is not valid syntax.

Comment: Maybe use `std::multiset` (or `std::set`)? Or is it something you're not allowed to do as well?

Comment: *What I want to do is check the first letter of a word, and then put it in the appropriate position in the list,* -- How is only checking the first letter considered "sorting"?

Comment: *I must use lists, and I cannot use the "sort()" function.*  -- The `std::list` [comes with a `sort()` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort).  Why is it you can't use it if you're already using `std::list`??  I've seen some really crazy requirements given by teachers, but this has to be one of the craziest I've ever heard of.

Comment: don't `push_back`. For each word, iterate through the list until you find the the first word with a first letter first letter after the words first letter and then insert the word ahead of the word you just found.

Comment: @user4581301 that's cringeworthy. And it's even more cringeworthy when I think it may be the expected solution/the best you can do with requirements as the OP stated.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add an iterator

```
std::list<string> mylist;
std::list<string>::iterator it; //now I can move through the list using this kind of like an index

for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
{
    if( line.compare(*it) >= 0) //If the line belongs before what *it is pointing to
    {
        mylist.insert(it,line);
        break;
    }
}
```

find out more about string::compare at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

find out more about inserting into a list at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/

Comment: I've barely just scratched the surface with C++, but have just been introduced to iterators by a fellow classmate. Everything I see here makes sense aside from one detail, that being 

line.compare(*it)

why does the '*' stand for? I want to think that is a pointer, but then it doesn't make sense to me as to why we must use a pointer

Comment: @BrettReinhard - an iterator is effectively a pointer, so you use *it to access (read or write) an element.

Comment: @rcgldr thanks for clearing that up. So does this essentially reference the address similar to how you pass an array ?

Comment: @BrettReinhard - not quite. Generally the internal format of std::list is a doubly linked list, so normally you can't index (assuming there's no clever overloading of an operator, std::list doesn't have random access iterators). So ++it advances via a next pointer and --it backs up via a previous pointer. std::list functions: begin() returns iterator to first element, back() returns iterator to last element, end() returns iterator just past last element.

Comment: @rcgldr ah I see, so this is a relatively heavy process in regards to resources, compared to say an array?

Comment: @BrettReinhard - true, there's the overhead of the linkage between nodes. Sequential nodes in a list can be randomly scattered in memory, which is cache unfriendly, making scanning relatively slow. Sorting is best done using a bottom up merge sort with a small array of pointers to nodes, as seen in [wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) or [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

```
multiset<string> l;

while (getline(myfile, line)){ //loops through and gets sayings
    l.insert(line);
}
```

This will add all the words and sort them automatically. The main difference between `multiset` and `set` is that the former allows duplicates, while the latter doesn't.

You can then iterate over `l` with a `for` loop:

```
for(string const& s : l) {
    cout << s << endl;
}
```